# Mac OSX, Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, macosx, macbook-pro, dual-boot, bootcamp

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Pro with Max OSX und Windows 7 (BootCamp) already installed.
Now there is a tutorial for installing Ubuntu on recent Mac OSX editions. However it does not mention what to do if you already have Windows 7 installed via BootCamp.

There are old tutorials how to install Ubuntu on Mac with Windows Vista installed via Bootcamp [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook/TripleBoot) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation).

Can I use the same procedure for a triple boot with Windows 7 and rEFInd instead of rEFIt?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You need to install a different boot loader like rEFInd.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

I recently did this to a 2010 macbook pro, and it worked find, except Ubuntu overwrote Windows' partition so I had to install in this order:  rEFInd, OS X, Ubuntu, rEFInd (over GRUB), and then Windows.

Make sure you've assigned all the space on the drive for the two EFI partitions, the mac partition, free space for the swap, and the two FAT32s (one of which ubuntu will obliterate, when you choose the custom setup, lest it merely take a partition and split it in half.)

There just alot of steps there, almost too many to detail in a simple answer.